# Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox has blurred screen

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, virtualbox

I tried to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox on my laptop (Windows 10 Home). I selected the ISO file I downloaded: `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`, and started it up from VirtualBox. But after starting, the interface became blurred and showed macroblocking like this :

[image: bright coloured pixelated screen]

I wondered if my ISO file goes wrong, but after using winMd5Sum it shows that the MD5 is the right one. I cannot find relevant messages. Could anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this but actually still don't know why.

The method is switch to console and then switch back to the GUI like the following:

1. press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Then the macro-blocking disappears and I can install Ubuntu as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Linux Mint 19 Tara in VirutalBox. I solved it with `Input -> Keyboard -> Insert Ctrl-Alt-Backspace`.